# Change all nested nodes or subsequent node properties

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
  every node/.style = {shape=circle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center, color=gray}]]

  \node {}
    child { node (a) {} }
    child { node (b) {}
      child { node (c) {}
        child { node (d) { } }
        child { node (e) {} }
        child { node (f) {} } }
      child { node (g) {} } };

  \node {}
    child { node (a) {} }
    child { node (b) {}
      child { node (c) {}
        child { node (d) { } }
        child { node (e) {} }
        child { node (f) {} } }
      child { node (g) {} } };

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'd like to change the color of all nested nodes without having to specify each one.

For example, the second graph could be some other. Specifying the node color does not cascade to the children.

It would be nice to be able to change the style and have it propagate to all remaining commands until changed again.

It doesn't have to be tree's but could apply in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I meant is this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,scopes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
  every node/.style = {shape=circle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center, color=gray}]

  \node {}
    child { node (a) {} }
    child { node (b) {}
      child { node (c) {}
            {[nodes={draw=blue}]  child { node (d) { } }
        child { node (e) {} }
        child { node (f) {} } }}
      child { node (g) {} } };


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And yes, it is necessary to post complete codes. If you want to learn from another post, you probably do not want to guess the libraries and packages the other users are using, do you?